# Syntax Highlighting + bash script ?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to format this post [Best collection of code for your .htaccess file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/best-collection-of-code-for-your-htaccess-file/19057#19057)

using the syntax highlighter, as you can see the default is messed up ( not just my post but several), so I added

<`!-- language: bash -->` I also tried `!-- language:lang-bsh-->` and `shell` but it's not being applied?

Comment: Ehm... is htaccess stuff supposed to be any "language" at all?

Comment: hmm I guess not, but some syntax highlighters have no problem with it usually using `shell` or `bash`, for instance http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ which this plugin is based off http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ works on my blog no problem.

Comment: Syntax here is done with Google Code Prettifier. I am not sure if your issue is a bug or it just doesn't work in that way that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I verified the syntax highlighting is being applied.  You can confirm this by viewing the source and look for:

```
<pre class="lang-bash default prettyprint">
```

Highlighting doesn't work correctly all of the time, there are a few edge conditions that can cause it to not display exactly as you would expect.